# Exception occurs in lambda express using Spring test

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, lambda, java-8

I have a DAO implementation which uses the Lambada expression as belows:

```
public RowMapper<User> getRowMapper() {
        return (rs, rowNum) -> {
            User result = new User();

            result.setUid(rs.getInt("uid"));

            return result;
        };
    }
```

When I use `gradle build`, the exception message shows like this:

```
ParseException in STDIN
Last useful checkpoint: "com.xx.daoimpl.MyDaoImpl.getRowMapper()"
Encountered " "," ", "" at line 61, column 27.
Was expecting one of:
    "instanceof" ...
    ")" ...
    "=" ...
    ">" ...
    "<" ...
    "?" ...
    "==" ...
    "<=" ...
    ">=" ...
    "!=" ...
    "||" ...
    "&&" ...
    "++" ...
    "--" ...
    "+" ...
    "-" ...
    "*" ...
    "/" ...
    "&" ...
    "|" ...
    "^" ...
    "%" ...
    "+=" ...
    "-=" ...
    "*=" ...
    "/=" ...
    "&=" ...
    "|=" ...
    "^=" ...
    "%=" ...
    "<<=" ...
    ">>=" ...
    ">>>=" ...
    ">" ...
    ">" ...
    ">" ...
    ">" ...
    ">" ...
    ">" ...
    ">" ...
    ">" ...
    ">" ...
    ">" ...
    ">" ...
    ">" ...
    ">" ...
    ">" ...
    ">" ...
    ">" ...
    ">" ...
    ">" ...
    "<" ...
    "<" ...
    ")" ...
    "<" ...
```

It refers to the ',' in `(rs, rowNum)` .But it works well when I use `gradle assemble`, which means that something happened when the test case using it. I'm using the embedded database of Spring for testing.

Can anyone help?

Comment: I guess, you are using a compiler which doesn’t support Java 8.

Comment: I have totally Java 8 environment now. I think Hilikus answer explains well. Thank you.

Comment: that is not a contradiction. I wasn’t talking about `javac` but *compiler* in general. Obviously, JavaNCSS contains some sort of builtin compiler which doesn’t support Java 8. Maybe the term “Java source code parser” would be more precise…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the same issue but are you using by any chance JavaNCSS?

I am getting the same error when using cobertura, as explained [here](https://github.com/cobertura/cobertura/issues/166#issuecomment-76793008) and it was reported as a problem in JavaNCSS not playing nicely with java 8

I hope this helps

Comment: Thanks, Hilikus. I think this can explian my problem.